# Change h1 tag's color globally using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement a dark mode that activates according to the current time.

That's how I change the body's background color:

```
if (darkMode) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#31403E';
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#F2EDE4';
}
```

Can I change the h1 tag's color in some kind of global way? Or do I have to check for the property `darkMode` in every single doc and then assign the proper color.

Comment: you can try css variable. I'm not sure you mean that but you'd still need to check the property in every single *doc*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern JavaScript, it could be:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('h1')
Array.from(elements).forEach(el => el.style.color = '#31403E')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom CSS stylesheet for dark mode:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {  
 color: white;   
  background: black
}
```

Where you can define your custom rules accordingly.

There's a nice trick about using `filter` as well that you can read a [bit further over here](https://dev.to/pqina/poor-man-s-dark-mode-using-css-filter-211n)

You can see this example over here:

https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/GLMLj

Where a class `.dark-mode` is set to the HTML document when toggling using

```
html.dark-mode {
    filter: invert(100%);
    img {
        filter: invert(100%);
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Comment: It's nice functionality, but they want to do it based on time, not a users preference.

Answer (score 1):

first of all they added dark mode preferences in css, they work like so:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  h1 {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

but a common workaround to this back when we were developing theme switches was adding a "dark" class to the body and doing the following in css

```
body.dark h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

IF YOU HAVE TO DO IT WITH JAVASCRIPT you have to loop through each and every h1's in the DOM, but it wont work on newly made h1s using javascript since it'll run on page load only as is.

```
let h1s = document.querySelectorAll("h1"); //gets all the h1s in the page

h1s.forEach( h1 => h1.style.color = "white");
```

Comment: The last option can still work if you put the code inside of a domchanged event

Comment: this is true, if you're using jquery. He said javascript so I assumed vanillaJS. In vanilla JS tho you have the mutation observer which is IMO the crowning jewel of javascript. Honestly, if he's changing the tag colors with javascript (with strings on top of everything) instead of with css, he's probably new to this whole thing and that's why I wrote everything like I did :)

Comment: Fair enough, just didn't want them thinking it was literally impossible :)

Comment: I thought I made that clear with the AS IS haha my bad

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can do it like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].style.color = "#000";
}
```